# Appending characters from two variables in bash

Tags: bash, loops

Hi I have outputs stored in two variables. Let's say:

```
echo "$varA"

Cow
Dog
Horse
```

And

```
echo "$varB"

1
2
3
```

I need the output to var3 like

```
Cow:::1
Dog:::2
Horse:::3
```

How can I do this with loops? If I use two loops, then the inner loop will run thrice for cow, dog and horse (each). I could not find a way to exit inner loop after 1 execution and there is no goto statement here.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just keep those "outputs" in arrays ? Like

```
varA=(Cow Dog Horse)
varB=(1 2 3)
```

And then you can prepare `var3` with a single loop like this

```
for i in "${!varA[@]}"; do
    var3[i]="${varA[i]}:::${varB[i]}"
done
```

You can read Arrays and Loops sections in bash manual for further information.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays (see @oguzismail's answer) are the better way to do this, but if you really need to do it with lines (presumably linefeed-delimited) in string variables, you can use the `lam` (laminate) command:

```
var3=$(lam <(echo "$varA") -s ":::" <(echo "$varB"))
```

Note that this uses process substitution (the `<( )` bits) to feed the two input variables to `lam` as input via filenames. This is a bash-only feature, so you must use it only in a bash shell. If it's in a script, use an explicit bash shebang line (`#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) or run it with `bash scriptname` (*not* `sh scriptname`).